# How to get matrix parameters programmatically from javax.rs.ws.core.UriInfo

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Is there any way to get the matrix parameters programmatically from `javax.rs.ws.core.UriInfo`? I know that you can get the query parameters as a `MultivaluedMap` by simply doing `uriInfo.getQueryParameters()`.  Aren't matrix parameters supported? Or they can be obtained calling `uriInfo.getPathParameters()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each part of a path between the `/../` is a [`PathSegment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html). And since matrix parameters are allowed for each segment, it makes sense to be able to access them via the `PathSegment`. Enter [`PathSegment#getMatrixParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html#getMatrixParameters%28%29) :-). So..

```
List<PathSegment> pathSegments = uriInfo.getPathSegments();
for (PathSegment segment: pathSegments) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = segment.getMatrixParameters();
    ...
}
```

It's also possible to inject a `PathSegment`

```
@Path("/{segment}")
public Response doSomething(@PathParam("segment") PathSegment segment) {}
```

You could also inject a `List<PathSegment>` for cases where the a path template regex allows for multiple segment matching. For instance

```
@Path("{segment: .*}/hello/world")
public Response doSomething(@PathParam("segment") List<PathSegment> segments) {}
```

If the URI were to `/stack/overflow/hello/world`, then the segments `stack` and `overflow` would be put into the list.

Also instead of injecting `PathSegment`, we can simply use `@MatrixParam` to inject the value of a matrix parameter

```
@Path("/hello")
public Response doSomething(@MatrixParam("world") String world) {}

// .../hello;world=Hola!
```

Comment: Be aware that
MultivaluedMap<String, String> extends MultivaluedMap<String, List<String>>